# Defining additional fields in a pivot table of a N-M relation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have a N-M relation in a GeoPackage, defined using QGIS 3.32.

For the sake of this question you can consider the "airports - airlines" example on the QGIS documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/joins_relations.html#many-to-many-n-m-relations

My setup is identical, except I have an additional field that describes the airports-airlines relation, so for example my pivot table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE airports_airlines (
   id serial NOT NULL,
   airport_fk integer NOT NULL,
   airline_fk integer NOT NULL,
   
   parking_cost integer
);
```

The QGIS docs then say: "*Now you can associate an airport with an airline (or an airline with an airport) using Add child feature or Link existing child feature in the subforms. A record will automatically be inserted in the airports_airlines table.*"

So far so good, except I want to define the value of `parking_cost` in the subform `airports_airlines_airport_fk_fkey` when I create the new relation entry.

I could not find a way to do that, is it possible?

The only way to specify a value for `parking_cost` I could come up with is by using the table editor *after* creating the record in the pivot, but that is very cumbersome, as it forces me to close the form, open the pivot table, search for the correct row, and then update it.